# How do I build ANTLR 3 grammars with import using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, antlr

I have a base grammar (`FooBase.g`) and two grammar that include it:

```
lexer grammar FooVariantA;
import base = FooBase;
...

lexer grammar FooVariantB;
import base = FooBase;
...
```

If I put all three files into `src/main/antlr`, the base grammar is compiled and this of course fails: it shouldn't be compiled, because it refers to some rules that are only defined in the "final" `FooVariantA` and `FooVariantB` grammars.

However, it seems I also cannot create `src/main/antlr/imports` subdirectory as with Maven, as Gradle ANTLR plugin never looks there:

> error(7):  cannot find or open file: FooBase.g; reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/test/test/src/main/antlr/FooBase.g (No such file or directory)

How can I make only the two final grammars compile and still be able to find the imported base grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be as simple as this:

```
generateGrammarSource {
    exclude ('**/*Base.g')
}
```